# Raising an event when anything is clicked except an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page containing a list of items with an image against each item.

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <div>
     <div class="text"> Text 1</div>
     <img src="../../Images/Notes.png" class="smallSizeLogo notes"
     </div>
     <div>
     <div class="text"> Text 2</div>
     <img src="../../Images/Notes.png" class="smallSizeLogo notes"
     </div>
  </li>
<\ul>
```

I want to raise an event if clicked anywhere in the html except the image. Is there a way to do it in jquery?

Comment: If you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 6):

Use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName != 'IMG'){
        //code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Another option: `$(document).on("click", "img", false); $(document).on("click", "*:not(img)", ...);` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbfg7ana/3/) It's another option, probably not a better one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thats actually a good workaround with a slight improvement,  no need to use `:not(img)`. https://jsfiddle.net/jbfg7ana/4/  Kudos on passing `false` for the *handler*, learned something new! :)